# How to convert "Some(123)" to 123 in scala

Tags: scala

I am having an issue with unwrapping Some(value) in scala. It is double wrapped value returning from a utility.

```
val result = "Some(Map(email -> Some(test@example.com), userId -> Some(123)))"
```

and return type of utility method is `Option[Map[String, String]]`

The expected result should be

```
val user = "123"
val email = "test@example.com"
```

Thanks

Comment: Are all the values just a string? or is that a typo? are you sore those will be Somes or are there options? if they are options, how will you deal with the case that the values don't exist?

Comment: Why is this happening? It look like that is a toString instead of the map value itself. Look like a design issue before.

Comment: In specific case, yes they are wrapped in string double-quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create variables from a `String` because identifiers (variable names) must exist at compile-time while strings are run-time objects.

But you can do something like this.

```
val inputStr =
      "Some(Map(email -> Some(test@example.com), userId -> Some(123)))"

val getSomeRE = raw"([^\s(]+)\s*->\s*Some\(([^)]+)".r
val rsltMap = getSomeRE.findAllMatchIn(inputStr)
                       .map(m => m.group(1) -> m.group(2))
                       .toMap
                       .withDefaultValue("no such")

rsltMap("email")   //res0: String = test@example.com
rsltMap("userId")  //res1: String = 123
rsltMap("phone")   //res2: String = no such
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

object Test extends App {
  val result = """Some(Map("email" -> Some("test@example.com"), "userId" -> Some("123")))"""
  val cm = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
  val tb = cm.mkToolBox()
  val str: Any = tb.eval(tb.parse(result))
  val parsedMap: Option[Map[String, Option[String]]] = str.asInstanceOf[Some[Map[String, Option[String]]]]

  println(parsedMap)
  val m: Map[String, Option[String]] = parsedMap.toList.flatten.toMap
  val userAndEmail = (m("userId").getOrElse(""), m("email").getOrElse(""))
  val user: String = userAndEmail._1.toString
  val email: String = userAndEmail._2.toString

  println(user, email)

}
```

Comment: but `result` is a `string`, so first you would have to convert the string into a `json/map`

Comment: What? you wanted result as String only right user = "123" and  email = "testuser@example.com"  this is the expected result you have given in the question.

Comment: Ok you mean your code it self is a string for that you will have to use reflection library